# Partial fractions decomposition of ${\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}}$

Tags: partial-fractions

Express in partial fraction form: $\displaystyle{\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}}$

I think is $\displaystyle{\frac{2x}{(x+2)^{2}} = \frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}}$

However when identifying $A$ and $B$, I'm not sure how to calculate A.

E.g.  $$2x = A\cdot (x+2) + B$$

Substitute $x=-2$

$2\cdot(-2)$ = $A\cdot (2-2) +B$

$-4 = B$

In other questions there is always another factor to multiply by at this stage.

Comment: If you then try for example $x=0$, you would get $0=2A+B$ and since you have found $B=-4$ you would get $A=2$

Answer (score 10):

If you go on to rewrite $2x=A(x+2)+B$ as $2x=Ax+(2A+B)$, then you can match up the coefficients of the polynomials (of $x$) on each side.  You must have

$$2=A\qquad\text{and}\qquad 0=2A+B$$

Now solve for $A$ and $B$.  The first equation (obviously!) says $A=2$. When you plug this into the second, obtaining $0=2\cdot2+B$, you get $B=-4$.

Incidentally, where you write "$2x={A\over x+2}+{B\over(x+2)^2}$," the left hand side of the equation should be $2x\over(x+2)^2$, not just $2x$.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from (as you almost wrote)
$$\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2},$$
rewrite as
$$\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{A(x+2)+B}{(x+2)^2}
      = \frac{Ax+(2A+B)}{(x+2)^2}.$$
From this, one sees that $2x = Ax + (2A+B)$, so that $A=2$ and $2A+B=0$ and thus $B=-4$ (as you correctly derived).

An alternative method, using substitution, starts again from
$$\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2} = \frac{A(x+2)+B}{(x+2)^2}$$
so that $2x = A(x+2)+B$. Substituting $x=-2$ gives $B=-4$ and thus $2x = A(x+2)-4$. Now substitute *any value other* than $-2$ (say $0$) for $x$, giving $0 = 2A-4$, so that $A=2$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 6):

May be somehow tricky but I love this kind ...
$$\quad{\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2} = \\\frac{2(x)}{(x+2)^2} = \\
\frac{2(x+2)-4}{(x+2)^2} = \\
\frac{2(x+2)}{(x+2)^2} +\frac{-4}{(x+2)^2} = \\
\frac{2}{(x+2)} +\frac{-4}{(x+2)^2} \\}$$

Answer (score 6):

Arriving at the formula

$$2x = A\cdot (x+2) + B$$

to reduce the problem to that of solving this polynomial equation for $A$ and $B$ is good start to the problem. So is solving for the value of $B$.

The method you're using to solve this equation — substituting $x = -2$ into your polynomial equation — is a *shortcut*.

You don't *have* to use the shortcut. (especially in a situation where it doesn't help!)

The two most common options to continue are:

- Use the definition of equality for polynomials. For each power of $x$, you get an equation asserting the coefficients on the two sides are equal, and you know how to solve systems of scalar equations. [This other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2513788/14972) gives more detail.
- Plug in literally any other value for $x$. You get an equation you can now solve for $A$.

Another simple option is to just solve the equation for $A$ in the normal fashion, after substituting in the known value for $B$. It turns out things cancel out and you get a number at the end.

Answer (score 5):

it must be
$$\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

For instance, you can multiply both sides by $(x+2)^2$ in

$$\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}$$

then

$$(x+2)^2\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}=(x+2)^2\frac{A}{x+2}+(x+2)^2\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}$$

now simplify

$$(x+2)^2\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}=(x+2)\cdot A+(x+2)^2\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}$$

and you can take the limit as $x\to 2$ both sides to show that:

$$ B = \underset{x\to -2}{\lim}{\ (x+2)^{2}\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}}=-4. $$

for $A$ take before the limit the derivative w.r.t $x$ in both sides to get

$$ A = \underset{x\to -2}{\lim}{\ \frac{d}{dx}{2x}=2. }$$

***Recall that, if $\ \displaystyle{f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{(x-r)^{k}}}$ and $(x-r)$ doesn't divide $p(x)$ you have:
$$f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{(x-r)^{k}}=\sum_{s=1}^{k}\frac{A_{s}}{(x-r)^{s}}$$
if you multiply by $(x-r)^{k}$ in both sides you will have:
$$ (x-r)^{k}f(x)=p(x)=\sum_{s=1}^{k}A_{s}\cdot(x-r)^{k-s}$$
and from that you have:
$$ A_{k}=\underset{x\to r}{\lim}{\ (x-r)^{k}f(x)} $$
and the others
$$A_{i}=\frac{1}{(k-i)!}\underset{x\to r}{\lim}{\ \frac{d^{k-i}}{dx^{k-i}}\left((x-r)^{k}f(x)\right)}$$***

Comment: Sorry I don't follow the last part. I am ending up with the denominator of B being cancelled out, leaving me unable to calculate A even after identifying B as -4. Without a factor left over, I can't see how to substitute something for x to only remove A.

Comment: You can compute unknown values $A$ and $B$ by taking the limit as $x\to 2$ in general. I will edit for to clarify how.

Comment: @Paddington: I wrote the explanation in general

Answer (score 3):

You're actually almost there. Just substitute your inferred value for $B$ into your equation, and you get
$$2x=A(x+2)-4$$
...now rearrange...
$$\require{cancel} A=\frac{2x+4}{x+2}=\frac{2\cancel{(x+2)}}{\cancel{x+2}}=2$$
..done!

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice method for rational functions that only have one repeated factor at the denominator: let the fraction be $f(x)=\frac{N(x)}{D(x)}$ where $D(x)=d(x)^k$.

The general form of the partial fraction decomposition is

$$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{a_1(x)}{d(x)}+\frac{a_2(x)}{d(x)^2}+\dots+\frac{a_k(x)}{d(x)^k}$$

Then, if you perform the division of $N(x)$ by $d(x)$, you can write $f(x)$ as

$$\displaystyle f(x)=q(x)d(x)+r_1(x)$$

where $\deg(r_1)<\deg(d)$. We then got

$$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{q(x)d(x)+r_1(x)}{d(x)}=\frac{r_1(x)}{d(x)}+\frac{q(x)}{d(x)^{k-1}}$$

so $r_1$ is actually $a_1$. By repeating the process with $q$, we can get all the other functions $a_2$,...,$a_k$.

Example with $\frac{2x}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{(x+2)^2}$: $2x=2(x+2)-4$, so $A=-4$ and $q(x)=2$. As $q(x)=0(x+2)+2$, we obviously have $B=2$. We obtain

$$f(x)=\frac{2(x+2)-4}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{2}{(x+2)}+\frac{-4}{(x+2)^2}$$

When $d(x)$ has degree $1$, we can use Synthetic Division to perform the division, so it is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

$$2x = A(x+2) + B$$

You just found that $B=-4$ and now you want to find the value of $A$. Well, let $B=-4$ and see what happens...

\begin{align}
   2x &= A(x+2)-4 \\
   2x+4 &= A(x+2) \\
   2(x+2) &= A(x+2)
\end{align}

Since this has to be true for all $x$, then $A=2$.

This is not a lucky coincidence. Substituting back into the original equation will always result in something solvable.